# Зависимости пакетов в linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, зависимости

Хотел установить сервер apache в kali linux нашёл видео, там предлагались пакеты, которые надо скачать и поставить.

Пакеты мной были успешно скачены и с помощью dpkg поставлены, но потом я узнал, что сервер apache здесь уже был, те пакеты оказались старыми и apt install не даёт ничего не обновить не установить из-за неудовлетворенных зависимостей.

Не знаю как исправить.
Вот лог:

```
   Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install».
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Зависит: libonig2 (>= 5.9.5) но он не установлен
                       Зависит: libqdbm14 (>= 1.8.74) но он не установлен
                       Зависит: php5-json
 libgd3 : Зависит: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) но он не установлен
          Ломает: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.1.1-4+b1) но 2.2.5-4 уже установлен
 libgd3:i386 : Ломает: libgd3 (!= 2.2.5-4) но 2.1.1-4+b1 уже установлен
 libncurses5 : Ломает: libncurses5:i386 (!= 6.0+20160213-1) но 6.1-1 уже установлен
 libncurses5:i386 : Ломает: libncurses5 (!= 6.1-1) но 6.0+20160213-1 уже установлен
 libtinfo-dev : Зависит: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1) но 6.0+20160213-1 уже установлен
 libtinfo5 : Ломает: libtinfo5:i386 (!= 6.0+20160213-1) но 6.1-1 уже установлен
 libtinfo5:i386 : Ломает: libtinfo5 (!= 6.1-1) но 6.0+20160213-1 уже установлен
 ncurses-bin : ПредЗависит: libtinfo5 (>= 6.1) но 6.0+20160213-1 уже установлен
 php5-cli : Зависит: libonig2 (>= 5.9.5) но он не установлен
            Зависит: libqdbm14 (>= 1.8.74) но он не установлен
            Зависит: php5-json
 php5-gd : Зависит: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) но он не установлен
 php5-mysql : Зависит: libmysqlclient18 но он не установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
```

Пытался выполнить предлагаемые apt команды, но всё также не даёт из-за зависимостей. Переустановить пакеты тоже не позволяет. Помогите, кто разбирается

Comment: `apt --fix-broken install` пробовали?

Comment: самое логичное: удалите те пакеты, которые установили не из дистрибутивного репозитория.

Answer (score 1):

Если у кого-то будет похожая ситуация, то вот, как я решил эту проблему:

1.Удаляем все пакеты, которые были криво установлены:

```
   sudo dpkg --purge NAME_PACKAGE
```

Их можно посмотреть с помощью команды

```
   sudo dpkg --audit
```

Выведет список всех ненастроенных пакетов.

2.Все пакеты ругающиеся на зависимость тоже удаляем той же командой)))

3.Делаем уже fix зависимостей:

```
   apt --fix-broken install
```

Далее выполняем полный upgrade:

```
   sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет)